# Mordell equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elliptic-curves, mordell-curves

Solve the integer equation $x^3+17=y^2$

In the book The Arithmetic of Elliptic curves of Silverman, in chapter 3, example 2.4, the author sad that this equation has eight solutions $(-2,3),(-1,4),(2,5),(4,9),(8,23),(43,282),(52,375)$ and $(5234,378661)$.

But in Elementary Number Theory of J Uspensky, page 400, the authors said that, these solutions is exactly all solutions of this Mordell equation.

I have try to solve it by follow some special case such as:
First, I have an expression
$$(y-\sqrt{17})(y+\sqrt{17})=x^3.$$
Moreover, $Z[\dfrac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}]$ is an euclidean domain and thus UFD. Next, we must find the GCD of $y-\sqrt{17}$ and $y+\sqrt{17}$ in $Z[\dfrac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}]$, we call it $d$. It is obvious $d$ is a divisor of $2\sqrt{17}$.
I'm stuck here. Somebody can give me some hint.
Thanks!

Comment: If both factors are divisible by $\sqrt{17}$, then $17\mid x$, which is impossible. This narrows it down to $d\mid 2$. Moreover, $x$ must be even (look at the equation modulo $8$). Now, how does $2$ factor  in $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}2\right]$?

Comment: I think it's done in  T. Nagell, L'analyse indéterminée de degré supérieur, Mémorial des sciences mathématiques 39, Paris, Gauthier-Villars, 1929, pp. 56–59, if you can access that.

Comment: we must solve the equation $\left(a+b\dfrac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}\right)\left(c+d\dfrac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}\right)=2$.

Comment: See also Ezra Brown & Bruce T. Myers (2002) Elliptic Curves from Mordell to Diophantus and Back, The American Mathematical Monthly, 109:7, 639-649, DOI: 10.1080/00029890.2002.11919894.

Comment: thank very much for all !